# Tor bridge on Azure Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, bridge, server

I am trying to set-up a Tor Bridge on Windows azure using Vidalia (Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Edition R2 in a VM) and while the Setup is no Problem and it connects to the Tor Network I don't manage to connect to it from the outside (timeout). I deactivated the Firewall of WS but still no luck.

Did anybody set-up a Bridge on Azure already (don't find much on that)? Not sure if it is an Azure specific thing or if I have Windows Server block the incoming traffic.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup an "endpoint" for that VM. No ports (except for remote management and RDP) from the public IP are open by default.
Just forward the necessary port (most likely 443 TCP) from your public IP to the same port on your private IP.